# Query a table mapping some columns within grouped rows to multiple columns in the same row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im using postgres and
I have a table that looks like the following:

```
f_id1 f_id2 f_id3 f_id4 value
 1      1    1     1    'aaa'
 1      1    1     2    'bbb'
 2      1    1     1    'ccc'
 2      1    1     2    'ddd'
 1      2    1     1    'eee'
 1      2    1     2    'fff'
 1      1    2     1    'ggg'
 1      1    2     2    'hhhh'
 2      2    1     1    'iii'
 2      2    1     2    'jjj'
```

I want to get query this table so that the result is that each unique f_id1, f_id2, f_id3 combination has a row, and each f_id4 is a column in that row with the value of value.

So for this table I would expect my output to be

```
f_id1 f_id2 f_id3 f_id4_1 f_id4_2
1      1     1     'aaa'   'bbb'
2      1     1     'ccc'   'ddd'
1      2     1     'eee'   'fff'
1      1     2     'ggg'   'hhh'
2      2     1     'iii'   'jjj'
```

We can assume that we know all of the possible f_id4 values beforehand (in this example 1 and 2).

We can also assume that we know all of the possible f_id1, f_id2, and f_id3 values beforehand (also just 1 and 2 in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation. This can be done using the `FILTER` clause for example:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=17e886e0dc29deb494e5cb957efe64d0)

```
SELECT
    f_id1,
    f_id2,
    f_id3,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE f_id4 = 1) as f_id4_1,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE f_id4 = 2) as f_id4_2
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```